# Limit of infinitely small oscillating functions

Tags: limits, functions

I have a question about limit of "small" oscillating functions.
Let's say I have the two functions of the image (really don't know what they could be). Is the limit for x that goes to infinity of the one in "black" 1 as the one in "red"?

[image]

Because if we have a function like f(x)=sin(x)*(1/x) it is clear that the limit for x that goes to infinity is 0, as it goes up and down of always smaller amounts around 0.
But of the function i drawn things are a bit different, as it goes only above y=1 to then "touch" y=1 back again. So I'm not sure if the limit is definite.

Comment: In that picture the limit is $1$.

Comment: The limit is surely $1$. An example of such a function could be $$f(x)=1+e^{-x/2}\sin^2x.$$ Another decreasing factor ($\to0$) could be used instead of $e^{-x/2}$. All depending how fast you want the oscillations to fade.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know the expression for the function you are considering but in these cases we need to bound the function as follows

$$1-\frac1x \le 1+\frac{\sin x}x\le 1+\frac1x$$

and then conclude by squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)+\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}=1.$$

Answer (score -1):

Yes it’s possible.... let assume a function f(x) which is the upper bound of our oscillating function h(x).we see that 1<=h(x) <=f(x) 
So here if f(x) convergence to 1 then h(x) must have to converge at 1. But if the oscillating function h(x) convergence to 1 we can’t say anything about f(x). 
Thank you